# SSMS removes parenthesis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to create a db view to azure ms sql db by using SSMS 19.

After i paste the sql query text to ssms (design view sql box)
and press test.

Test passes but the actual where part of the query clause is not correct anymore, ssms (or azure sql) removes parenthesis which causes wrong resultset.

SQL text pasted:

```
.... 
WHERE 
(
(t1.[c1] IS NOT NULL AND t1.[c2] LIKE 'AAA1') 
) 
OR
.....
```

Outcome after pressing ssms test sql button:

```
....
WHERE 

(t1.[c1] IS NOT NULL) AND (t1.[c2] LIKE 'AAA1') 

OR
.....
```

As one can see the logic changes. Outer parenthesis were removed and each comparison is now surrounded by their own parenthesis.

Is there a way to turn off SSMS (or azure sql db) modifying the parenthesis. Or any other way to maintain the desired logic

Comment: The logic does not change, merely the formatting does. Precedence in T-SQL means that `(A AND B) OR C` is equivalent to `A AND B OR C`. If you don't want the formatting to change, don't use these "helpful" designers, just write your own `CREATE VIEW` statement. The SQL Server engine isn't going to modify the query.

Comment: `the logic changes` no, it doesn't. That's just a formatting change that highlights the individual conditinos. SSMS is just a client tool, not the database. There's no "SSMS or Azure SQL", SSMS connects to Azure SQL, just like Visual Studio, Azure Data Studio, TOAD or any other tool. Other client tools can have different, configurable formatters too.

Comment: `which causes wrong resultset.` did you encounter an actual problem or are you assuming there will be a problem? `AND` [has higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) than `OR`, both in binary logic and SQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `AND` having higher precedence than `OR` is a common programming language choice, but boolean algebras typically give conjunction and disjunction the same precedence and require full parentheses for expressions involving both. As far as formulas go, not giving either precedence leads to more elegant displays of the symmetries between the operators. Of course T-SQL is not exactly a language to care about elegance...

Comment: Don't use these visual designers. They are a relic from about 20 years ago and don't support a lot of modern query syntax. They do also have bugs and even when not introducing bugs they can introduce unwanted changes to the query syntax - such as the "expansion" here in order to show it in a grid better presumably https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gr9V.png

Comment: I stand corrected. The resultset is the same when created using query window vs using SMSS with changed parenthesis. Thank you @JeroenMostert and Panagiotis Kanavos. And i agree with Martin Smith ... learning the hard way.

Comment: Too many anyway, be grateful!